# How can I revoke a custom model permission for a user in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am writing an app that has a large form with a lot of fields that have to be submitted in order. Each section of the form is available only when a user has the permission to access it, these permissions are defined within one of the models and the admin user gives them to the users when the conditions are met.

What i'm trying to do now is for the user permission to be deleted for that user when they submit that section of the form. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Here is the model:

```
class PartidosUsuarios(models.Model):
    idUsuario = models.ForeignKey(User)
    idFifa = models.ForeignKey(PartidosFifa, null=True)
    idPartido = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    PaisL = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Local = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, default=0)
    Visita = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, default=0)
    PaisV = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Resultado = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Puntos = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, default=0)
    Capturado = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="No")
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("grupos", "Puede ver partidos de grupos"),
            ("octavos", "Puede ver partidos de octavos"),
            ("cuartos", "Puede ver partidos de cuartos"),
            ("semis", "Puede ver partidos de semis"),
            ("final", "Puede ver partidos de final"),
        )
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.idPartido)
```

And here is the view:

```
@login_required(login_url="/")
def inicio(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Pronosticos(request.POST)
        for i in range(47):
            pronostico, _ = PartidosUsuarios.objects.get_or_create(idUsuario=request.user, idPartido=request.POST.get("idPartido"+str(i), ""), PaisL=request.POST.get("PaisL"+str(i), ""), Local=request.POST.get("Local"+str(i), ""), Visita=request.POST.get("Visita"+str(i), ""), PaisV=request.POST.get("PaisV"+str(i), ""), Capturado="Si")
            if pronostico.Local > pronostico.Visita:
                pronostico.Resultado = "Local"
                pronostico.save()
            elif pronostico.Visita > pronostico.Local:
                pronostico.Resultado = "Visita"
                pronostico.save()
            elif pronostico.Local == pronostico.Visita:
                pronostico.Resultado = "Empate"
                pronostico.save()
    partidos_usuarios = PartidosUsuarios.objects.order_by("idPartido")
    partidos_fifa = PartidosFifa.objects.order_by("Partido")[:64]
    context = ({"partidos_fifa": partidos_fifa, "partidos_usuarios": partidos_usuarios})
    return render(request, "brasil/inicio.html", context)
```

In this case the permission that should be deleted upon submitting the form is the one called "grupos"

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it isn't clear for me if you have a `role` called **grupos** and you want to remove permissions for that `role` submitting forms or if you have a custom permission called **grupos**. But in both cases you can use: `permissions.utils.remove_permission(obj, role, permission)`

Where:

**obj**

The content object for which a permission should be removed.

**role**

The role for which a permission should be removed.

**permission**

The permission which should be removed. Either a permission object or the codename of a permission.

So, in your view, just call this function at your convenience.

For more info for working on permissions see: [Django API for manage permissions](https://pythonhosted.org/django-permissions/api.html)

Comment: I created a custom permission called grupos. It's not clear to me what I need to place as "obj" in you solution, also, do I need to import something out of the django user models?

Comment: obj stands for an `user` or a group. Also you can use `some_user.user_permissions.remove(permission, permission, ...)`.

Comment: I wrote it in like this: 
`permiso = User.user_permissions.remove(request.user, "grupos")
            permiso.save()`
However i'm getting this attribute error: 'ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'remove'
Can you tell me if this was the correct way of doing it?

Comment: You don't have to put the `User` model. Look this link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization under the section `Permissions and Authorization`